# WordPress Navigation Menus for footer and header

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to WordPress and currently working with it. I'm having a trouble with my navigation menus. The supposed different set of menus on my header and footer are the same. What would be the problem?

Here is my code:
***for header.php***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
  <head>
   <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset');?>">
   <meta charset="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
   <?php wp_head(); ?>
  </head>
  
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

 <div class="container">

 <!-- site-header -->
 <header class="site-header">
  <h1><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
  <h5><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h5>

  <nav class="site-nav">
   <?php
    $args = array(
     'theme-location' => 'primary'
    );
   ?>
   <?php wp_nav_menu(  $args ); ?>
  </nav>
 </header><!-- /site-header -->
```

***for footer.php***

```html
 <footer class="site-footer">
  <nav class="site-nav">
   <?php
    $args = array(
     'theme-location' => 'footer'
    );
   ?>
   <?php wp_nav_menu(  $args ); ?>
  </nav>

  <p><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?></p>

 </footer>


</div> <!-- container -->


<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

***for functions.php***

```html
<?php

function WordpressSample_resources() {

 wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','WordpressSample_resources');

//Navigation Menus
register_nav_menus(array(
 'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu'),
 'footer' => __( 'Footer Menu'),
));
```

Answer (score 1):

WordPress Navigation Menus for footer and header

**add below code in header.php file.**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
        <head>
            <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset');?>">
            <meta charset="viewport" content="width=device-width">
            <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
            <?php wp_head(); ?>
        </head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <div class="container">

    <!-- site-header -->
    <header class="site-header">
        <h1><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
        <h5><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h5>

        <nav class="site-nav">
            <?php
            $header_menu_defaults = array(
                'theme_location'  => '',
                'menu'            => 'Primary Menu',
                'container'       => '',
                'container_class' => '',
                'container_id'    => '',
                'menu_class'      => '',
                'menu_id'         => '',
                'echo'            => true,
                'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
                'before'          => '',
                'after'           => '',
                'link_before'     => '',
                'link_after'      => '',
                'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                'depth'           => 0,
                'walker'         => ''
            );
            wp_nav_menu( $header_menu_defaults );
        ?>
        </nav>
    </header><!-- /site-header -->
```

**add below code in footer.php file.**

```
<footer class="site-footer">
    <nav class="site-nav">
         <?php
        $footer_menu_defaults = array(
            'theme_location'  => '',
            'menu'            => 'Footer Menu',
            'container'       => '',
            'container_class' => '',
            'container_id'    => '',
            'menu_class'      => '',
            'menu_id'         => '',
            'echo'            => true,
            'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
            'before'          => '',
            'after'           => '',
            'link_before'     => '',
            'link_after'      => '',
            'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
            'depth'           => 0,
            'walker'         => ''
        );
        wp_nav_menu( $footer_menu_defaults );
    ?>
    </nav>

    <p><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?></p>

</footer>
```